# Mongodb java api: WriteResult#getN()

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm writing some Java code using MongoDB with Java API and I'm unsure of some part of the Javadoc.

In a multi-thread context I use [DBCollection.html#update(com.mongodb.DBObject, com.mongodb.DBObject)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#update%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29) to update a **unique** document, but I saw that two threads could try to write concurrently. In this context, I observed that only one write was done, as Mongodb seems to use optimistic write lock, but I wanted to find out programmatically in which thread the write was the one who wrote, and which one was not. As a "no update" behavior was silent (I mean no exception or something), I searched into the API some way to answer my issue and after some tests found out this method: [WriteResult#getN()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html#getN%28%29)

```
public int getN()
    Gets the "n" field
    Returns:
```

The description is, hum... not really exhaustive. My tests showed that the thread that win the write has a getN() that return 1, and the other 0.

So my question is: Could someone confirm this ?

Comment: why do you say there was a "failure"?  if the object specified was not found then there was nothing to update.  There would be no update, not a write failure.

Comment: Sorry, as a non-native english speaker, I sometime fail to tell my mind the right way. ;) I meant that it did no update silently, which was my issue actually. I will correct my wording.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the GetLastError() [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command#getLastErrorCommand-ReturnValue)

The return value from the command is an object with various fields. The common fields are listed below; there may also be other fields.

- ok - true indicates the getLastError command completed successfully. This does NOT indicate there wasn't a last error.
- err - if non-null, indicates an error occurred. Value is a textual description of the error.
- code - if set, indicates the error code which occurred. connectionId - the id of the connection
- lastOp - the op-id from the last operation

For updates:

- n - if an update was done, this is the number of documents updated.

So in this context, 'get "n" field' means get n which is the number of documents updated.  Without "multi" being set to true it can only be either 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks for finding this infos, it gets me sure about my algorithm now. ^_^