# why WriteConcern is being ignored in MongoDB Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to execute a blocking call to `db.collection.insert(List<DBObject>, WriteConcern)` method with the MongoDB java driver. No matter what I use in WriteConcern: `SAFE`, `FSYNC_SAFE`, `FSYNCED`, `ACKNOWLEDGED`, ... I can't grant the write has been performed...at least not the way I'm doing it right now. Check the code:

```
WriteResult result = collection.insert(list, WriteConcern.FSYNC_SAFE);
if (result.getN()> 0){      
    System.out.println("Alleluyah!");
return true;
}
```

From what I've read [here](http://www.littlelostmanuals.com/2011/11/overview-of-basic-mongodb-java-write.html), `FSYNC_SAFE`, should be the way to go... The data is being written, but the call to `result.getN()` is always zero. If there is no way to check if a write has been completed...

Why create the `getN()` method in the first place?? Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? I do need to check this insert has been performed. I can query the collection and check, but it just looks overkill to me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894101/mongodb-writeresult-getn-always-returns-0) post regarding the `getN()` method. It only gives information on the number of documents affected by an update or remove operation.

I'm no expert but consider this quote from the MongoDB wiki on the `getLastError` method:

> You should actually use a write concern like `WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED` instead of calling `getLastError()` manually.

As far as I understand it using a sufficient level of `WriteConcern` and getting a `WriteResult` back means that the operation was successful and no error occurred. Check out the [article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/#write-concern-reference) and [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/) on WriteConcern in the wiki as well.

Since you explicitly want to verify that the insert operation executed correctly you could do something like this:

```
WriteResult result = collection.insert(list, WriteConcern.FSYNC_SAFE);
CommanResult commandResult = result.getLastError();
if (commandResult.get("err") != null) {
    System.out.println("Alleluyah");
return true;
}
```

Inserting a document with `WriteConcern.FSYNC_SAFE` calls the `getLastError()` method - [source](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/#writeconcern-option-for-single-write-operation). If the level of `WriteConcern` isn't strict enough calling `getLastError()` may result in an error - examine the [WriteResult code on github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/WriteResult.java) . If no error has occurred than the err field will be `null`, otherwise it will contain an error message - [source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/#getLastError.err).

Comment: +1 for providing so many links, and a correct answer for the snippet too :) Still, getN() should be removed then, it only leads to confusion in my opinion. Thank you Nikolay.